# QGraphicsScene - deleting items - clear() crashes

Tags: qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsScene and buttons on that. I want to delete that buttons, but method clear() doesn’t work.

mainclass.cpp

```
MainClass::MainClass(QWidget* parent)
  :QMainWindow(parent)
{
  ui.setupUi(this);
  scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
  ui.graphicsView->setScene(scene);
  QPixMap picture(":/MainClass/Resources/picture.jpg");
  pixmapItem = scene->addPixmap(picture);
  pixmapItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
}

void MainClass::hideButtons();
{
  scene->clear();
}
```

Maybe there is a way to do this differently?

Function hideButtons is invoked by other function (from class MainClass).

EDIT: ok, I had some mistakes in code, so I now know why it didn’t work, but now it crashes every time I try to clear the scene using:

```
scene->clear()
```

as same as

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> allGraphicsItems = scene->items();
for(int i = 0; i < allGraphicsItems.size(); i++)
{
  QGraphicsItem *graphicItem = allGraphicsItems[i];
  scene->removeItem(graphicItem);
  delete graphicItem;
  scene->update();
}
qDebug()<<"End of hideButtons()";
```

If I comment line with “delete graphicItem” it doesn’t crash, but items are not deleting from the scene, because when I tries to readd them, I get:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget 0×5f547d8; already embedded
QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget 0×5f6a818; already embedded”
```

Items, that I remove, don’t have parent.
Interestingly, program crashes after writing "End of hideButtons()", so there must be some method (from beyond my classes) that tries to invoke deleted object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, by not deleting buttons. I rewrote my program, so I only hide and show buttons. And it works fine.

After some reflection: I think that better solution is to set graphicsView as a parent of button than adding that button to the scene as a widget. First solution allows you to make changes to that button simplier.